# Which packages can be used for qualitative data analysis and coding in R version 4.13?

Tags: r, package

I have already tried using RQDA but it no longer works for version 4.13 and I can't seem to change my version to 4.00 from the global options menu since RQDA only works till version 4.

Comment: Hi Bharvi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid questions asking for recommendations for software packages are off-topic here. If you have a specific example of a problem you are trying to solve, including data and code you have tried already to solve it, then we would be happy to help. Please edit your question to include these, otherwise your question is likely to be closed. Thank you.

Comment: At the moment I don't have a specific problem that I could pinpoint and ask for help but thank you for your suggestion I would keep that in mind for the next time.